# Can I use libVLC's Python bindings with Python 3.x?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, vlc, libvlc

I want to use libVLC to build a video scheduler for Linux. The [PythonBinding](https://wiki.videolan.org/python_bindings) wiki for libVLC states that it can be used with Python version greater than 2.5. However, I couldn't find any information explicitly stating that it does or does not work with Python 3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you're linking includes a [compatibility layer](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=generated/3.0/vlc.py;h=5f16932f8b7b9e132567b247a8025b2a1df901da;hb=HEAD#l65) that checks the python version and sets up some variables in order to make the code work in both Python 2 in Python 3:

```
if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    str = str
    unicode = str
    bytes = bytes
    basestring = (str, bytes)
    PYTHON3 = True
    ...
else:
    str = str
    unicode = unicode
    bytes = str
    basestring = basestring
    PYTHON3 = False
    ...
```

This looks like a good hint that Python 2 and 3 are meant to be supported at the same time.

(Note that many libraries use a standard helper library called [`six`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) to keep the code polyglotic, instead of doing this manually like `vlc.py`, but I understand the authors of this library wanted to avoid external dependencies.)

Comment: Also, the [bindings classifiers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-vlc) inlcude both `Programming Language :: Python :: 2` and `Programming Language :: Python :: 3`, which should tell the same without needing to look at the code itself.

Comment: @mata good catch! I didn't even check if the code is also on pypi.